# C# Async Server/Client Architecture

Tags: c#, asynchronous, client, chat

first post ever on stack overflow!

Anyway...I'm trying to teach myself networking programming in my spare time and I've reached a snag I just cant wrap my head around.  After playing with synchronous networking methodology over a few days I decided to make a client/server program that could:

- Handle multiple concurrent connections
- Handle multiple streams of communication
- Have true two way communication

On a more general level I want to make a chat program.  Multiple client connections to a server that can send and receive data individually with no problems...but also have the server send data from each client to the others.

Now I haven't gotten as far as I'd like to yet so I'm here for a little guidance.  I can't seem to get my loops working properly and I'm sure it has to do with the asynchronous nature of the code...for whatever reason I just can't seem to figure out whats wrong.  Here's the the blocks of code:

Server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
// Client  socket.
public Socket workSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 1024;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
// Thread signal.
public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public AsynchronousSocketListener()
{
}

public static void StartListening()
{
    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

    // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
    // The DNS name of the computer
    // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
    //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    //IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback;
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3000);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                content.Length, content);
            // Echo the data back to the client.
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}


public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Client.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class Program
{
    public static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void Connect(EndPoint remoteEP, Socket client)
    {
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

        connectDone.WaitOne();
    }
    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                //  Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    string response = state.sb.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3000);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Connect(localEndPoint, sock);
        string packet;
        while (true)
        {
            packet = Console.ReadLine();
            packet += "<EOF>";
            Send(sock, packet);
            Receive(sock);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain in a bit more detail exactly _what's_ not working properly with your loops?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an assignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any loops or waithandles when you go asynchronous. Just fire away another beginAccept inside AcceptCallback and you server will start listening again after accepting a client.

If your problem is that the server responses only once and then shuts down, then, well, that is what you say it to do in a SendCallback - it sends stuff and then shuts down. Call handler.beginReceive instead of handler.shutdown (you'll have to carry your StateObject all the way down to this callback, not just handler).

Comment: "you'll have to carry your StateObject all the way down to this callback, not just handler"

Should I store the StateObject that is created in AcceptCallback in a global variable then call it in ReceiveCallback?  To me it looks like we want to keep the same state object reference throughout the "thread" or whatever we'd call the Async (state is most appropriate i suppose lol)

Comment: If you just store it in a global variable, then all your clients will use it, not just one. The way you do it now is correct. After all,  that's what AsyncState property is made for - to carry over the same state from one callback to another.

Comment: But if you are writing a chat, then you'll have to keep all the StateObjects in a global list to broadcast any messages you receive from a client to others.

Comment: handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

Comment: state.buffer and state are out of scope if used in ReceiveCallback....and creating a new object would be senseless.  Since we can't use a global either...should I pass it as a parameter?

Comment: You don't have access to the stateObject because you pass only handler, and not the entire stateObject to Send function. So yes, it should have been passed as a parameter. Creating a new one is possible, but wasteful.

Comment: Thank you so much!  My misunderstanding was how states were passed/represented.  Got that all sorted...now time to pass broadcasts to all the clients :).  Thanks again!